# Does anyone have experience with a private Launchpad instance?

Tags: version-control, project-management, versioning, launchpad

Has somebody already installed and run launchpad on its own server? I'd like advice as I wasn't able to find any on the web. Besides, the official team gives scary remarks on having its own launchpad. They also say that a lot of administration scripts aren't included in the distributed sources and that the user has to reinvent them by himself (then I figured they actually don't want anybody to have its own).

Although, I'm keen to have mine, it's for one private project developed by 2 to 3 coders. I'm going to rent a dedicated server with the appropriate Ubuntu server. But before I do so, I'd like to know:

- If I install one instance and then keep using that **specific** stable version (I'm sure we won't need to upgrade and sync with the official launchpad upstream at all) do I take huge risks like losing all data?
- Does it crash sometimes?
- Does it require the development of plenty admin. scripts?
- Is the setup and initial configuration hard (or not yet documented)?
- If you were me, and would like to work with Bazaar, what other project management platform would you go for?
- How's launchpad's backup system?

Comment: You might try asking over on Ask Ubuntu. Occasionally Launchpad devs come through there. I know there have been a few conversations on the launchpad-dev mailing list regarding this (sorry no specific links). Loggerhead is what provides the code view. It's easily installed on its own, and might be more suited for a small team. https://launchpad.net/loggerhead

Comment: I think loggerhead is now part of launchpad and I'll definitely use it either way. But I'm also interested in all the bugs,QA, blueprints and also translations (well barely everything in there :)). But before choosing I'm kinda looking for some "success stories".

Comment: I supposed you already picked another solution, like you I spent too much time trying to install my own instance of Launchpad and gave up after filling 5 bugs, one of them being [no information regarding running launchpad on yout own domain](https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/786212). I am wondering what you are using now, and if you are happy with it.

Comment: Also added to http://askubuntu.com/questions/44297/is-there-anyone-running-his-own-instance-of-launchpad

Comment: Hi Sorin, well I didn't find an alternative yet, I'm trying things but I didn't get to a final good result. I'll keep you posted ;)

Answer (score 4):

I do not think that there is anyone using Launchpad other than Ubuntu. If you wonder why I say this, please check https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/786212

Comment: Hehe indeed. Look at this too: https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+question/152080 (I got a bit pissed off though ^^)

Comment: Yeah, I also tried in vain to install launchpad. I realised that even though the code is open that it isn't a high priority to make it easily installable for others because the installation the devs care about is already running. I can't say I really blame anybody for this. I installed Gforge before and that was also a real mission and mess. Easy installation is just not a priority for projects with only a few expected installations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sloecode](https://launchpad.net/sloecode) for hosting bazaar branches and as andrewsomething said you can use [loggerhead](https://launchpad.net/loggerhead) for a web view of the code. Another option to consider is [fusionforge.org](http://fusionforge.org/) I think on Ubuntu you can apt-get that these days.

Comment: @CoolStraw I'm not sure what you mean with "This is hosted".

Comment: Like on demand :) you sign in and use their own hosting.

Comment: @CoolStaw you are too cryptic man, I don't get what you are saying or asking. The main fusionforge.org is hosted yes, but you can easily install your own one as far as I understand you can even apt-get it on Ubuntu.