# Self hosting bazaar repositories

Tags: hosting, repository, bazaar

Are there any interesting projects allowing `bazaar` repositories management? I'd like at least project + group + user management. Web based code browsing isn't critical but would be nice too. I know of [bazitis](https://launchpad.net/bazitis), but considering it's pretty much dead I'm not sure I want to use it.

Unfortunately launchpad doesn't seem like a good solution either, taking over the system and not being very easy to deploy quickly. Are there some alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I'll copy my [answer from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420774/does-anyone-have-experience-with-a-private-launchpad-instance/6011524#6011524) here.)
You can use [sloecode](https://launchpad.net/sloecode) for hosting bazaar branches and you can use [loggerhead](https://launchpad.net/loggerhead) for a web view of the code. Another option to consider is [fusionforge.org](http://fusionforge.org/) I think on Ubuntu you can apt-get that these days.

Comment: I've seen sloecode, but unfortunately it's not stable for me (throws exceptions on every other request). Their docs are completely incorrect in some places too :(

Answer (score 1):

There is `bzr_access` script in bzr sources (look inside contrib directory).

Comment: Probably I didn't make it very clear, but I wanted the user access to be managed using the web interface - without messing around with local files directly.